# Nested model creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

I'm playing around with the Rails Console and was wondering why the following code doesn't work:

```
Question.create(body: "Why this does not work?", answer_attributes: {body: "Some Answer"})
```

It's weird cause when I do this:

```
question = Question.new(body: "Why this does not work?", answer_attributes: {body: "Some Answer"})
question.answer
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
=> #<Answer id: nil, body: "Some Answer", question_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

It seems that the answer object is associated with the question object...

Now if I try to save the object, it doesn't work:

```
question.save
```

I get this:

```
 => false
```

When I call .errors on it I get this:

```
question.errors
@messages={:"answer.question_id"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Both objects are new so it's kinda normal the question object doesn't have an id.

I know I could create the answer object by creating a question first and then call update_attributes on it... Or simply by creating a question and then calling answers.build on it...

My question is... Is there a way for a child model to get its parent's id upon creation?

Oh and if you're wondering, I do have a validation that requires an answer to have a question_id value.

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question...

I needed to put this code:

```
:inverse_of => :question
```

So my question model would look like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of :question

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

My answer model would look like this:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question

  validates :question, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

using `create` respects mass-assignment so make sure you add `attr_accessible :answer_attributes` to your `Question` class, or use

```
Question.create({body: "Why this does not work?", answer_attributes: {body: "Some Answer"}},)
```

Comment: can you post your Question and Answer classes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, in order to allow mass assignment for nested models. Refer to the api reference to have more information on the topic